# How to implement infinite scroll with Github API Repositories List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api

I'm fetching github repositories from api.github.com/users/ncesar/repos and i wanna get only 10 items, then after scrolling, load more items. I have tried to implement myself but i dont know how to adapt it to array slice(that is limiting my array length to 2, just for testings).

This is my current code

```
class SearchResult extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      githubRepo: [],
      loaded: false,
      error: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadItems(this.props.location.state.userName);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (
      nextProps.location.state.userName !== this.props.location.state.userName
    ) {
      this.loadItems(nextProps.location.state.userName);
    }
  }

  loadItems(userName) {
    axios
      .get(`${api.baseUrl}/users/${userName}/repos`)
      .then((repo) => {
        console.log('repo', repo);
        if (repo.data.length <= 0) {
          this.setState({ githubRepo: '' });
        } else {
          this.setState({ githubRepo: repo.data });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          this.setState({ error: true, loaded: true });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      githubRepo, loaded, error,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="search-result">
        {error === true ? (
          <h1 style={style}>User not found :(</h1>
        ) : (
          <section id="user-infos">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8">
                {githubRepo
                  .sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count) return 1;
                    if (a.stargazers_count > b.stargazers_count) return -1;
                    return 0;
                  }).slice(0, 2)
                  .map(name => (
                    <UserRepositories
                      key={name.id}
                      repoName={name.name}
                      repoDescription={name.description}
                      starNumber={name.stargazers_count}
                    />
                  ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResult;
```

Just to clarify, the sort is ordening repos by stars count.

What i have tried:

```
//setting theses states and calling this function
page: 1,
totalPages: null,
scrolling: false,


  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadContacts(); //carrega os contatos iniciais
    this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {//escuta o scroll
      this.handleScroll(event);
    });
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    const { scrolling, totalPages, page } = this.state; //pega os 3 pra fora do state
    if(scrolling) return; //se ja está scrollando, retorna true
    if(totalPages <= page) return; //se o total de páginas é menor ou igual a page
    const lastLi = document.querySelector('ul.contacts > li:last-child');//pegando o último li
    const lastLiOffset = lastLi.offsetTop + lastLi.clientHeight;
    const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
    var bottomOffSet = 20;
    if(pageOffset > lastLiOffset - bottomOffSet) this.loadMore();
  }

  loadMore = () => {
    // event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      page: prevState.page + 1,
      scrolling: true,
    }), this.loadContacts);
  }
```

But i dont know where i can pass the page parameter. The explanation of this code: it was used on a API with page number and per page parameters. The problem is that Github API does not offer this in repositories list, so, this is why i'm using slice.

Comment: "I have tried to implement myself" - where? I don't see any scroll detection going on in here at all?

Comment: @James Updated. I hadnt placed the code because i thought it was not relevant.

Comment: No problem, all code is relevant when you need help with it. So what part doesn't work?

Comment: I dont know how i can pass the page parameter to the array slice @James

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller

You should create one component (controller) that will download data from github and will provide fetching more function to `react-infinite-scroller`

And create a other component that will receive and render the data

Comment: do you have any idea about how i can implement to my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I just need to pass a state to slice and increment that state with a function.

This is the code:

```
            {githubRepo
              .sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count) return 1;
                if (a.stargazers_count > b.stargazers_count) return -1;
                return 0;
              }).slice(0, pageNum)
              .map(name => (
                <UserRepositories
                  key={name.id}
                  repoName={name.name}
                  repoDescription={name.description}
                  starNumber={name.stargazers_count}
                />
              ))}
<button onClick={this.loadMore}>Carregar mais</button>
```

And loadMore

```
  loadMore = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      pageNum: prevState.pageNum + 5
    }));
  }
```

Now i just need to stop using button and implement to use scroll